# Creating Video with Private Link via API

Tags: vimeo

I'm scoping out a project with the Vimeo API in which a user uploads a protected video.

I see the API allows for uploading a video with a password via `privacy.view`.

However, Vimeo also has the ability to upload a video that's only sharable with a private link. I'm not seeing a reference in the API that indicates it's possible to create this via the API. Basically, a user would upload a private video and the API returns the "private link" for that video.

I was hoping someone with more expertise might be able to confirm.